# What does the error ( mapping values are not allowed here) about yaml schema validation mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, tavern

I am using `tavern` as a test framework for my python project. The mock server for the test is defined in a yaml file:

```
test_name: Test phonebook service

stages:
  -name: Make sure we can create new contact
   request:
     url: http://localhost:9301/v2/contact
     method: POST
   response:
     status_code: 200
     body:
      id: 1
```

When I run the test I get this error:

```
/Users/joey/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py:579: in fetch_value
    self.get_mark())
E   yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
E     in "/Users/joey/dev/iress/devel/phonebook-service-api/src/api/tavern-tests/test_contact.tavern.yaml", line 5, column 11
```

The line5 is `request:` but I don't know what wrong with that. I don't think it is a `tavern` problem while it looks more like `yaml` schema validation issue.

Comment: Paste it into an on line yaml linter and you will see the same error. If you get rid of the - in front of name, it works.

Comment: It doesn't work if I remove `-` in front of name because it expects `stages` to be a list

Comment: I simply meant that the yaml passes , hoping that would help you narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I make it work by placing a `space` between `-` and `name`.

```
test_name: Test phonebook service

stages:
 - name: Make sure we can create new contact
   request:
     url: http://localhost:9301/v2/contact
     method: POST
   response:
     status_code: 200
     body:
      id: 1
```